# In pyqt5 is there a way to replace figure canvas with my refreshed basemap when I click ok button?

Tags: pyqt5, matplotlib-basemap, redraw

```
class PlotCanvas(FigureCanvas):


def __init__(self, parent=None, width=50, height=40, dpi=100):
    fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
    self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

    FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
    self.setParent(parent)

    FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
            QSizePolicy.Expanding,
            QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)



    m = Basemap(ax=self.axes)


    m.drawcoastlines()
    m.fillcontinents(color=(255./255., 237./255., 163./255.) )
    m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,91.,30.))
    m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,181.,60.))
    m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
```

I plot the above canvas inside a `qmainwindow`. Afterwards I want this canvas to be replaced by a refresh `basemap` that is called in another function. The problem is that when I call the other function and draw the refreshed map, it opens in a new window instead of replacing the old one.

Comment: here is the other basemap that uses some variables that user sets (lat_min,lat_max,lon_max,lon_min)

Comment: xi, yi = m(lonGrid, latGrid)
        
        print(lonGrid,latGrid)

        cs = m.pcolor(xi,yi,bathymetry)

        m.drawcoastlines()
        m.fillcontinents(color=(255./255., 237./255., 163./255.) )
        # draw parallels and meridians.
        m.drawparallels(np.arange(lat_min,lat_max,1.))
        m.drawmeridians(np.arange(lon_min,lon_max,1.))
        plt.set_cmap('jet')
        plt.title('Περιοχή')
        plt.show()

Comment: Don't post code in comments, [edit] your question and include it there

Comment: @barbsan i am sorry but im kinda new in python and this site.. do u have any idea how i can fix my problem?